# AWS - Amplify - Is there a way to change or update user's email using amplify from the front end?

Tags: aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I am using cognito email address and amplify Auth to sign in... Is there a way to change or update user's email using amplify from the front end?

I don't get the flow yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just found it: **updateUserAttributes**

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple,

https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/allow-users-to-change-their-email.html and https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js#managing-user-attributes

You need to provide the user via `currentAuthenticatedUser` and then call `updateUserAttributes` providing the `user` reference and the new email address.

```
const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, { email: fields.email });
```

For more options on how to manage users information in Amplify with React see this page.

https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/manage-user-accounts-in-aws-amplify.html

Comment: Side note, if you setup Cognito to use `username` authentication and not email you will need to completely `amplify remove auth` add it back with `email` auth in order for the above to work.

Also if you are using user pool groups, you will need to remove these first then delete the Cognito resource. (all via Amplify) if you mess up `amplify pull --restore`.